# Remove site name from og:title Yoast seo plugin

Tags: wordpress, seo

i have a problem with yoast seo plugin; i want to remove the sitename from og:title.

Actually, the meta og:title, show the content that is TITLE OF PAGE - TITLE OF THE SITE.

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="The title of the page or blog - The title of the site" />
```

How i could remove the sitename, so the og:title show only the title of the page or blog?

```
public function og_title( $echo = true ) {
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $title = WPSEO_Meta::get_value( 'opengraph-title' );
        if ( $title === '' ) {
            $title = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()->title( '' );
        }
        else {
            // Replace WP SEO Variables
            $title = wpseo_replace_vars( $title, get_post() );
        }
    }
    else if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $title = ( $this->options['og_frontpage_title'] !== '' ) ? $this->options['og_frontpage_title'] : WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()->title( '' );
    }
    else {
        $title = WPSEO_Frontend::get_instance()->title( '' );
    }

    /**
     * Filter: 'wpseo_opengraph_title' - Allow changing the title specifically for OpenGraph
     *
     * @api string $unsigned The title string
     */
    $title = trim( apply_filters( 'wpseo_opengraph_title', $title ) );

    if ( is_string( $title ) && $title !== '' ) {
        if ( $echo !== false ) {
            $this->og_tag( 'og:title', $title );

            return true;
        }
    }

    if ( $echo === false ) {
        return $title;
    }

    return false;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 3):

There is a filter that you can use to modify the og title in Yoast SEO plugin: **wpseo_opengraph_title**

Add this function to your functions.php. If necessary, replace the separator character.

```
add_filter('wpseo_opengraph_title','mysite_ogtitle', 999);

function mysite_ogtitle($title) {

    $separator = " - ";
    $the_website_name = $separator . get_bloginfo( 'name' );
    return str_replace( $the_website_name, '', $title ) ;
}
```